# Two preg_match functions, whats the difference

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Would someone to kind enough to explain to me what the difference (if any) between the two functions below is? I have been using the first for quite sometime to validate passwords. having done a little reading my head is now telling me the second function does exactly the same thing?

```
preg_match("/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}$/", $string);
```

Rewritten:

```
preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}/", $string);
```

Any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}$/` - 6 characters, containing at least one digit, uppercase, and lowercase

`/[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}/` - **a substring of** 6 or more characters, which must be uppercase, lowercase, or digits

- `aA1___` is matched only by the first
- `111111` is matched only by the second

---

Note that enforcing stronger rules can result in weaker passwords - [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: The second preg_match with return true with other characters too. '4Dd$' for example will return true

Comment: The second matches also `&é"12abAB*****` because there are no anchors.

Comment: Cheers guys, just a quick note though.

"And please, when validating passwords, only enforce a minimum length" I have only enforced a minimum length.

and "aA1___" is matched by both